# Query binding not working in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a pretty simple query that's failing in CI:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tenant (name, image, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$this->db->query($sql, $name, $image, $url);
```

When I try to execute this query, I end up with the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?, ?, ?)' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO tenant (name, image, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>
> Filename: models/Tenant.php
>
> Line Number: 107

All of the variables used are defined properly, and I can get it to work no problem by converting it to this:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tenant (name, image, url) VALUES ('$name', '$image', '$url')");
```

There's nothing special about any of the variables - they're all just strings. What needs to happen for query binding to work here?

Comment: the query prototype expects **two** parameters, not four. In a nutshell, you have to pass an array as a second parameter (either associative array OR non-associative, in this case non-associative array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at documentation about [query binding](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings). `query` takes two arguments. Your bindings should be in one array.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tenant (name, image, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$this->db->query($sql, array($name, $image, $url));
```

Answer (score 1):

You Must pass 2nd parameters in array form :

> Query Bindings :Bindings enable you to simplify your query syntax by letting the system put the queries together for you. Consider the following example

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

> The question marks in the query are automatically replaced with the
>   values in the array in the second parameter of the query function

For more information [read here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) in detail

Comment: I just wonder where it clearly states that array must be used. It would be nice if the query function also could take a single variable as the second parameter. I mean in case there is only one binding-variable